# GORM findAll + cannot pass dynamic List as named parameter

Tags: grails-orm, hql

I am getting the following exception at the following HQL.

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String.
```

Obviously I'm missing something but can't, can't figure it out. Can somebody please advise?

```
def methodA(List<String> key1List, List<String> key2List){
   def results = DomainX.findAll("from DomainX x where (x.key1 in (:key1_s)) and (x.key2 in (:key2_s))",[key1_s:key1List, key2_s:key2List])
}
```

The following works but not the above one:

```
def methodA(List<String> key1List, List<String> key2List){
   def results = DomainX.findAll("from DomainX x where (x.key1 in (:key1_s)) and (x.key2 in (:key2_s))",[key1_s:['ABC'], key2_s:['DEF']])
}
```

Comment: what version of grails you are using?

Comment: Grails version 2.4.4

Comment: Tested on grails 2.4.2 and works fine. How you are calling this first methodA?

Comment: It was my mistake. key2List was like [[key2_a], [key2_b]]; GORM was expecting this to be a flattened list [key2_a, key2_b]. Thanks You Guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. key2List was like `[[key2_a], [key2_b]]`; GORM was expecting this to be a flattened list `[key2_a, key2_b]`.